# Apache Solr 6.6.1 server crashed when indexing via Nutch 2.3.1

Tags: java, apache, indexing, solr, lucene

I have configured Apache Solr 6.6.1 on a system with 4 GB RAM. I have 2GB to solr. I have to index about 1 million documents to Solr. Nutch was running on seperate system. When I executed job to index documents, solr instance was down and following message was appeared in logs

```
Running OOM killer script for process 1437 for Solr on port 8983
Killed process 1437
```

My solr instance is not in cloud mode. Why this problem has happened?

Answer (score 0):

Because you're out of memory. `OOM` stands for `Out Of Memory`, and the "OOM killer script" is an internal handler that tries to kill any other running processes instead of taking the whole server down. In this case it apparently didn't work, and you're left with a borked server.

You can try to [give Solr more memory through the JVM](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/jvm-settings.html), or try to commit more often (if you're only committing and the end of the indexing process, a lot of data might have to be kept around in memory).

If the server is also being queried while you're indexing, the server will also have a set of active caches and memory allocated to avoid performing the same sorting/filtering operations each time.